# How to upload video on facebook using facebook sdk 4.6 on iOS8

Tags: objective-c, ios8

How to upload video on facebook using facebook sdk 4.6 on iOS8.This is the code i used:

```
FBSDKAccessToken *token = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection = [[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc] init];


NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mov"];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               videoData, @"video.mov",
                               @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                               @"Video Test Title", @"title",
                               @"Video Test Description", @"description",
                               nil];

FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:params tokenString:token.tokenString version:@"nil" HTTPMethod:@"POST" ];
[connection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    else
        NSLog(@"Success");
}];

[connection start];
```

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. it works for me.

> NSDictionary *dictPrivacy = [NSDictionary
>                                    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS",@"value",
>                                    nil];
>       SBJSON *jsonWriter = [SBJSON new];
>       NSString *strPrivacy = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:dictPrivacy];
>
> ```
> NSString *Url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Video" ofType:@"MOV"];
>
> NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: videoUrl];
> //NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:rtfUrl];
> NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
>                                videoData, @"video.mov",
>                                csString, @"title",
>                                strPrivacy,@"privacy",
>                                nil];
> FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
>                               initWithGraphPath:@"/me/videos"
>                               parameters:params
>                               HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
> [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
>                                       id result,
>                                       NSError *error) {
>
>     if (error)
>     {   
>        NSLog(@"fail to upload over Facebook");
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         NSLog(@"Successfully uploaded over Facebook");
>     }
>
> }];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In Graph APi 2.3+

```
FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
            video.videoURL = videoURL;
            FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
            content.video = video;
            [FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

NOTE: Video URL should be Assest URL.

Answer (score 0):

If one don't want to use FBSDKShareVideo.

```
- (void)shareVideoOnFacebook:(NSString*)videoURL{

if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]){


    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoURL];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   videoData, @"video.mov",
                                   @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                                   @" ", @"title",
                                   @" ", @"description",
                                   nil];
    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"/me/videos"
                                  parameters:params
                                  HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error){

         if (!error){
             NSLog(@"sharing result = %@",result);


         }
         else{
             NSLog(@"error=%@",error.localizedDescription);
         }




     }];

} else{

    FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    loginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative;

    [loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

        if (error || result.isCancelled) {

            NSLog(@"fb error= %@",error.localizedDescription);


        }
        else{
            NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoURL];
            NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           videoData, @"video.mov",
                                           @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                                           @" ", @"title",
                                           @" ", @"description",
                                           nil];
            FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                          initWithGraphPath:@"/me/videos"
                                          parameters:params
                                          HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error){

                 if (!error){
                     NSLog(@"sharing result = %@",result);

                 }else{
                     NSLog(@"error=%@",error.localizedDescription);
                 }


             }];

        }

    }];

}
```

}